# AS3 - HitTest not working finely

Tags: actionscript-3

The player doesn't stops instantaneously but goes little further into the obstacle by 10 px (by which im positioning it the player += 10).

update function

```
function update(evt:Event) {
    if(rightMovementAllowed) {
        player.x += 10;
    }
    if(lefttMovementAllowed) {
        player.x -= 10;
    }
}
```

check collision function

```
function checkCollision() {
    if(player.hitTestObject(enemy)) {
        rightMovementAllowed = false;
        leftMovementAllowed = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When a player collides with an object, send them to their previous position, ie the position they were in immediately prior to the impact.
Alternatively, by getting the dimensions (width and height) of the player and the collision object, you could put the player in a position so that it is only JUST touching the collision object. For example, having determined a collision has taken place, you could add the following function to your Player Class:

```
function collision(collisionObject:MovieClip) {
    if (x>_oldX) {
        x = collisionObject.x - ((this.width * 0.5) + (collisionObject.width * 0.5));
    } else {
        x = collisionObject.x + ((this.width * 0.5) + (collisionObject.width * 0.5));
    }
    if (y>_oldY) {
        y = collisionObject.y - ((this.height * 0.5) + (collisionObject.height * 0.5));
    } else {
        y = collisionObject.y + ((this.height * 0.5) + (collisionObject.height * 0.5));
    }
}
```

This function assumes that your Player and collisionObject MovieClips are positioned with their reference points at their centres. Also _oldX and _oldY are private Player variables that keep track of its previous position.
Note that this function will behave oddly if triggered every frame. It should be called only when a collision has just taken place.